# Backtrack through coin collection matrix to determine the optimal path?

Tags: c++, matrix, dynamic-programming

I've been assigned the, from what I've seen, fairly common problem when learning dynamic programming of having a nxm matrix of coins with a robot starting at the top left of the matrix [0,0] and trying to reach the bottom right of the matrix while picking up as many coins as possible. The robot is only allowed to move right and down. I have successfully been able to count the maximum number of coins that can be collected from the matrix, my code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int CoinCollection(int coinGrid[5][6])
{
  int F[5][6] = {0};
  F[0][0] = coinGrid[0][0];
  for(int j = 1; j<6; j++)
  {
    F[0][j] = F[0][j-1]+coinGrid[0][j];
  }
  for(int i=1; i<5; i++)
  {
    F[i][0] = F[i-1][0] + coinGrid[i][0];
    for(int j = 1; j<6; j++)
    {
      F[i][j] = max(F[i-1][j], F[i][j-1])+coinGrid[i][j];
    }
  }
  return F[4][5];
}

string RobotPath(int coinGrid[5][6])
{
  return "";
}

int main()
{
  int grid[5][6] = { 
{0,0,0,0,1,0}, 
{0,1,0,1,0,0}, 
{0,0,0,1,0,1}, 
{0,0,1,0,0,1}, 
{1,0,0,0,1,0} };
  cout << "Max amount of coins collected is " << CoinCollection(grid);
  cout << "\n\nRobot's path is" << RobotPath(grid);
}
```

The instructions I have say to hardcode the grid being used, so I don't have to change what I have to be flexible with inputs. The second part of the problem instructs to output the path that the robot should follow to reach the max number of coins (where the RobotPath method is). From the help I've received from my professor, I need to backtrack from the final solution to the beginning for this, but I'm at a loss for how to do this.

Comment: if you want to backtrack, you have to leave yourself 'breadcrumbs' or something like it to track back along. 
For each F[i][j] you are filling up, don't just take the max, but also remember which was the winner. Once you arrive at the goal you can runn back along the path of winners

Comment: Backtracking is often performed with recursion.

Comment: And dynamic programming is used to prevent recursion

Comment: I hadn't really thought of it like that. It doesn't necessarily eliminate recursion, but one of the big goals is certainly to reduce the amount of recursion.